# Installing with Dual boot, raid 0, 3 drives

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, raid

I’ve searched but don’t see my issue covered which is a variation of the dual boot Ubuntu install issues many seem to have. The way I see it, mine should be more straight forward but that doesn’t seem to be the case thus far.

I’m trying, with no success to install Ubuntu on an unused 3rd drive on my Alienware m17 r3 which is not and will not be used for windows at all. I have 3 NVMe 512gb drives, two of which are configured raid 0 as the boot drive. Do I need to mess with the raid configuration at all if I just want to install on the 3rd drive? In fact, I don’t even want the computer to ask me to choose OS at startup. I’m perfectly happy pulling up the bios if I ever want to get into the Ubuntu system.

Any tips for an easy install without messing with the windows drive would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you choose from "BIOS" to boot from the third drive? If so, I guess you can put everything related to the new installation of Ubuntu (including the new EFI partition) onto the third drive and select the drive to boot from "BIOS" every time.

Comment: You must partition in advance & include an ESP on 3rd drive. And do a work around as Ubiquity installer only installs boot files to first drive. Old but current bug with various work arounds: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 More info on work arounds: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator Most UEFI will let you disable drive, so you can use the install to one drive option without disconnecting other drives.

Comment: I would, temporarly remove the raid drives, and then install Ubuntu ( it will see your third drive as first ( and only ). If you have installed Ubuntu, shut the computer down and do a test. If ok, install the other drives again ( remenber which drive in used to be in which slot/ put a little sticker on the first one f.e. ). This way you won't encounter any problems ( don't put your third drive in the first slot either, leave it where it is. I'm pretty sure your UEFI/BIOS will be able to boot from it).